# counting using join information

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables.

One table records orderstock which has **FK_stock** and **FK_orderNo**

I want to count the number of orders each item of stock has. The following code works correctly to do this:

```
(1)
    SELECT orderstock.FK_orderNo, Count(orderstock.FK_stock) AS CountOfFK_stock
     FROM stock INNER JOIN orderstock ON stock.StockID = orderstock.FK_stock 
    GROUP BY orderdemo.FK_orderNo
```

However, I wish to add to this such that only stock items which are non perishable (stock.perishable=0) are listed. So something like

```
SELECT orderstock.FK_orderNo, Count(orderstock.FK_stock) AS CountOfFK_stock 
FROM stock INNER JOIN orderstock ON stock.stockID = orderstock.FK_stock 
WHERE stock.perishable=0 
GROUP BY orderstock.FK_orderNo
```

How do I access information relating to the FK_stock to make this work? When I attempt to combine information from the stock table to this end, each item of stock is counted separately.

Results from (1)

```
 FK_OrderNo     CountOfFK_Stock     
 9      10
104     8
105     3
106     10
107     8
108     10
109     11
110     9
```

Desired results (something like):

```
 FK_OrderNo     CountOfFK_Stock     
 9      7
104     8
105     3
106     4
107     7
108     2
109     11
110     6
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help

Comment: @VR46 Well all of the attributes, table names, etc. listed above are fake in order to make the question more appealing...

Comment: yeah for the fake column names provide some data and expected result

Comment: stock.StudentID = orderstock.FK_stock - are you sure that matching studentid with a stockid is a good idea? If yes, then your 2nd query seems correct. Pls describe any error message you received or unexpected behaviour you encountered because we do not know your database structure and data.

Comment: This sample output will not help without the source data (orderstock and stock tables)

Comment: Try using conditional sum as `sum(case when stock.perishable=0 then 1 else 0 end) as CountOfFK_stock ` and remove where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `conditional count`

Move the `where` clause filter to `Count Aggregate` and make the count aggregate to count the record only when `stock.perishable = 0`.

```
SELECT orderdemo.fk_orderno, 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN stock.perishable = 0 THEN 1 
             END) AS nonperishable_count 
FROM   stock 
       INNER JOIN orderdemo 
               ON stock.studentid = orderdemo.fk_stock 
GROUP  BY orderdemo.fk_orderno
```

`Count` Aggregate can be replaced by `SUM` aggregate as well. Something like this

```
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN stock.perishable = 0 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END) AS nonperishable_count
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this shortly.

Comment: Although you may be right in the end, stricktly based on the question, this answer may not be correct. The technique described by you is useful if you do not want to count all records returned by the query for whatever reason. However, in the question only 2 fields are required: order number and count of order items that satisfy a certain criteria. This can be achieved by filtering for the criteria in the where an counting the results.

Comment: The difference between the 2 approach is only visible in handling those orders, which do not have any order items corresponding to the criteria. Filtering in the where condition with inner join would see such orders left out from the resultset, with your method these would included with 0 shown next to them. There is no indication in the question how these orders should be displayed in the result.